# XML serializer in a loop

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I am trying to serialize data from a dataGridView, which I put into a class, to then write to a file. However, I have a problem, where the serializer would put each object in it's own "file", instead of all the objects in one; when I open the .xml file, you can see this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <MyClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Column1>XXX</Column1>
    <Column2>YYY</Column2>
  </MyClass>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <MyClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Column1>ZZZ</Column1>
    <Column2>AAA</Column2>
  </MyClass>
```

Here is the code that I use to serialize with. How do I fix this, so that when I open the .xml file, that I only get a single file, not split up like above? Do I have to add all the objects into a list and then write from the list?

```
private void expXML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("Filename.XML");
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            MyClass abc = new MyClass(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value), dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
            ser.Serialize(writer, abc);
        }
        writer.Close();
    }
```

Comment: You have to create a class that serves as root-element and contains all the data as collection. You can´t have multiple root-elements in your xml.

Comment: `Do I have to add all the objects into a list and then write from the list?` seems you may have answere ur own issue or else you can create a wrapper around all the class and serialize the wrapper as @HimBromBeere suggested

Comment: As @HimBromBeere said, make another class which holds a property of List<T> of type MyClass and add each object to that list, then use serialize on that root class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I followed the suggestions and my own hunch; here is the edited code, that properly serialized the data:

```
private void expXML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<MyClass> newList = new List<MyClass>();
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<MyClass>));
    TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("Filename.XML");
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        MyClass abc = new MyClass(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value), dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
        newList.add(abc);            
    }
    ser.Serialize(writer, newList);
    writer.Close();
}
```

Comment: better answer than mine

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
private class MyClassList
{
   IEnumerable<MyClass> Root{  get;  set;}
}

private void expXML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myClassList = new MyClassList();
    myClassList.Root = new List<MyClass>();

    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
    TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("Filename.XML");
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        MyClass abc = new MyClass(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value), dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
        myClassList.Root.Add(abc);

    }
    ser.Serialize(writer, myClassList);
    writer.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create("Filename.XML", new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true }))
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("root");
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        MyClass abc = new MyClass(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value), dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
        ser.Serialize(writer, abc);
    }
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```

Here, we manually create the root element using `XmlWriter`, which allows you to repeatedly write using the `XmlSerializer`.

---

However, it is much better to use a collection like `List<MyClass>` and (de)serialize it entirely.

In addition, I would advise you to do data binding:

```
var list = new List<MyClass>();
// fill the list

// bind collection to control
dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
```